# Is my line of reasoning correct for considering this fixed field as a simple extension over $GF(7)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Suppose we have the field of rational functions $GF(7)(t)$ in the indeterminate $t$ over $GF(7)$. Deﬁne $σ,τ ∈ Aut(E)$ by $σ(t) = 2t$ and $τ(t) = 1 /t$. Set $G = <σ,τ>$ and $F = Fix(G)$.

There was a question in a past exam paper I was looking at that said considering the minimal polynomial of $t$ over $F$ describe $F$ as a simple extension of $GF(7)$. I want to make sure I understand this correctly

Firstly we note that $\sigma(t^3)=t^3$ so $t^3 \in Fix(<\sigma>)$ , also we have that $\tau(t+1/t)=t+1/t $ so $(t+1/t)\in Fix(<\tau>)$.

So then we have that $(t^3+1/t^3)\in Fix(G)$.

Next we note that $t^6-t^3(t^3+1/t^3)+1=0, $so a minimal polynomial for $t$ over $GF(7)$ is $x^6-x^3(t^3+1/t^3)+1$.

So then as a simple extension of $GF(7)$ is $F$ just $GF(7)(t^3+1/t^3)$ ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what argument allows you to conclude that $X^6 - (t^3+1/t^3) X^3 + 1$ is minimal, or that $F$ is exactly $GF(7)(t^3+1/t^3)$ (you've certainly proven that $F$ contains $GF(7)(t^3+1/t^3)$ though).

Comment: @JoelCohen For the first question `, I'm pretty sure that we can make the argument that the galois group is size six so then the minimal polynomial of t is degree $\leq 6$ and also that t has degree 6 over the fixed field , so the degree of the min poly must be 6 , and above is a polynomial which is irreducible over GF(7) with t as a root . For the second question I'm not sure either I don't really understand what it means to say describe F as simple extension over GF7 in this context

Comment: It is polite to include a link to [the previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3288397/11619). Not all your readers will have seen it, and some may see this after a year or so, and be very confused :-)

Comment: Mind you, I don't really see finite fields here so I removed the tag.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen ah thank you, I'll be sure to do that in future when I ask a question which is a continuation of another :)

Comment: Anyway, if you write $u=t^3+t^{-3}$, then that minimal polynomial has coefficients in the field $K=GF(7)(u)$. Because the minimal polynomial is sextic, it follows that $[K(t):K]=6$. Here obviously $K(t)=GF(7)(t)$, so $[GF(7)(t):GF(7)(u)]=6$. By Galois theory $[GF(7)(t):F]=6$ and also $K\subseteq F$. The tower law implies that $[F:K]=1$. In other words $F=K$ as you suspected.

Comment: While we are at it: [Lüroth's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%BCroth%27s_theorem) states that all the subfields of $GF(7)(t)$ are simple extensions of $GF(7)$. The same result applies to intermediate fields between $K$ and $K(t)$ over any field $K$.